# Hibernate Search: Index is not updated (works on local cluster but not on dockerized containers on AW$)

Tags: docker, hibernate-search, infinispan, clustered-index

Currently using Hibernate Search 5.10, I prepared it to use an infinispan as a directory provider, and in a local 4-cluster JBOSS, it works okay.

However, when the containers are on AWS and there's any operation on the entity, the changes are not reflected when I perform a search again. The most mysterious thing is it works in my local docker, but not on AWS. Thoughts on this?